# return something Kafka consumer when no more messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to return statsu = success
After Kafka consumer read all massage in that day, it must to running all the time.

I tried to google it but not found any solution but if you have any link or something to resolve it, please share it back to me.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

> While efficient, one problem with asynchronous consumers is detecting when they are idle. You might want to take some action if no messages arrive for some period of time.

> You can configure the listener container to publish a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` when some time passes with no message delivery. While the container is idle, an event is published every `idleEventInterval` milliseconds.

And

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#event-consumption

> You can capture these events by implementing `ApplicationListener` — either a general listener or one narrowed to only receive this specific event. You can also use `@EventListener`.

Comment: I cant make it now code i only have
@KafkaListener(topics = "RecurringFailedTopic", groupId = "my_group_id")
    public void getRecurringFailedMessage(String xmlMessage) {
//            service.startKafkaRecurringFailed(xmlMessage);
    }
and I add all the code but how can i call it or use it

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Don’t put code in comments. Edit the question instead, and be more clear.